# Не могу понять как отправляется почта

Tags: debian, sendmail

У меня есть сервер, на котором стоит Debian 8 и система управления Vesta CP. Уже не вспомню почему, но я ставил ssmtp для отправки почты. Его настраивал на гугловскую почту. Потом удалил его, но почта по прежнему идет через гугл.

Конфигов нету, как мне найти почему почта отправляется именно так?

Comment: Посмотреть логи почты - `/var/log/mail.info`.

Comment: в этом файле всего 2 строки `ul  3 06:25:05 w4u exim4: ALERT: exim paniclog /var/log/exim4/paniclog has non-zero size, mail system possibly broken
Jul  4 06:25:05 w4u exim4: ALERT: exim paniclog /var/log/exim4/paniclog has non-zero size, mail system possibly broken`

Comment: Почтовик на вашей системе повидимому не стоит. Мало информации. Добавте команнды отправки почты.